# Simulink: Add custom property to a block

Tags: simulink

I would like to add a new property to a selected block.

For example, when i write

```
get_param(gcb,'ObjectParameters')
```

I would like to see my custom property.

I tried the command `add_param` but without success.

```
add_param(gcb,'Foo','foo')
Input argument 1 must be a block diagram
```

Comment: Is the block a custom masked block? If yes, you can add a mask parameter and access it through get_ / set_param

Comment: @pmb, the blocks are not custom (Inport, Outport, etc.)

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure you can add params to the standard blocks... a workaround would be to mask these standard blocks, thus making them custom, and build your own library with them.